# Programmatically configure hardhat network

Tags: contract-deployment, hardhat, hardhat-deploy, configuration

I'm trying to programmatically configure the hardhat network (instead of specifying it in `hardhat.config` and using `--network nname`) before deploying a smart contract.

So, something like this:

```
import { ethers } from "hardhat";

function deployContract(network_info) {
  /* configure hardhat with given network info */
  /* i.e. set the rpc url & private key */


  // basic deploy code as seen in docs
  const Greeter = await ethers.getContractFactory("Greeter");
  const greeter = await Greeter.deploy("Hello, Hardhat!");
  await greeter.deployed();

  ...
}
```

does hardhat currently have functions which can let me do this? I couldn't find a lot of documentation on it, any help or guidance would be appreciated.